# Data type is changed when listening message from message queue in RabbitMQ 2.3.6

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using Spring Rabbit 2.3.6 for my spring application. I have list of Comment entity and send to message queue via this function

```
public void deletePost(long postId){
    Post post = postRepository.findById(postId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new PostNotFoundException(String.valueOf(postId)));
    List<Comment> comments = postBase.getComments(post);
    postRepository.delete(post);

    //post event
    Map<String, Object> inputs= new HashMap<>();
    inputs.put(InputParam.OBJECT_ID, postId);
    inputs.put(InputParam.COMMENTS, comments);
    messagingUtil.postEvent(SnwObjectType.POST, SnwActionType.DELETE, inputs);
}
```

Listening message

```
@RabbitListener(queues = MessagingConfig.QUEUE)
public void consumeMessageFromQueue(Map<String, Object> inputs) {
        
}
```

And this is data I received after listening message. Data type of each element in comment list have been changed, and I can't use it as Comment.

[image]

Have you any solution to data type from not being changed?

Updated: Messaging config

```
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfig {
    public static final String QUEUE = "javatechie_queue";
    public static final String EXCHANGE = "javatechie_exchange";
    public static final String ROUTING_KEY = "javatechie_routingKey";

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(ROUTING_KEY);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(converter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: To say your data type is being "changed" is a bit of a misnomer. Types as such only exist within your Java program, and RabbitMQ is not part of your program. RabbitMQ holds your messages in a language-agnostic format. Your Java program then deserializes each MQ message by binding its data to a Java object. And because your consumer method has `Map<String, Object>` as its parameter, that's the Java type it's binding to. If you replaced that with a custom class which `implements Serializable`, and which has`objectId` and `comments` fields with the types you expect, that might solve your problem.

Comment: @GaryRussell I updated messaging config

Comment: My comment was wrong; deleted; I didn't notice you were sending/receiving a `Map`.

Comment: Element types of container types such as `Map` cannot be inferred. Rather than using a `Map`, it would be better to create a POJO with the fields and types you desire and jackson will then correctly decode each field with the correct type.

Comment: it mean that I need create many rabbit listener for each POJO instead of only a listener for all